# Accessing value using get method or member directly?

Tags: c++, function, class, member

```
class SomeClass
{
    int classMember;
    public:
    int GetMember();
    bool IsPositive();
};

int SomeClass::GetMember()
{
   return classMember;
}

bool SomeClass::IsPositive()
{
    int val = GetMember();  //Case#1. Accessing value using get method
    int val = classMember;  //Case#2. Accessing value directly

    return (val > 0);
}
```

Question: Does using Case#1 have any advantages over Case#2 or vice versa? Are there any overheads (even the tiniest) in using get method as compared to the member directly?

Comment: There's probably some tiny overhead in calling the getter function simply because the function needs to be constructed and thrown onto the stack in addition to accessing the member variable. Also, you should just `return (val > 0);` as opposed to that hullabaloo you have there taking up 6 lines.

Comment: Given a reasonable compiler, there should be no overhead in execution. There's a much larger overhead in lack of readability though.

Comment: Check the disassembly and you'll know for sure...

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I agree. `return (classMember > 0);` is way more readable that `return (GetMember() > 0);`

Comment: That's only the tip of the iceberg though. Consider something like adding two numbers together: `a.member = b.member + c.member` versus `a.set_member(b.get_member() + c.get_member())` -- or even `a.set_member(b.add_values(b.get_member(), c.get_member())`.

Comment: you can directly access members if you are implementing a class, unless you have extra checking in get method. any function call has overhead, so if you want to be efficient, you want to decrease the number of function calls. personally, i think it's a sick using simple getter like this in a class.

Comment: Case 1 may be helpful later for debugging, profiling, inheritance...  and I don't think there's any function call overhead since it will be inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it really depends on how your compiler chooses to do something. The best way to see if there is a difference is to look at the disassembly.

```
    int val = classMember;
010C4869  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
010C486C  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
010C486E  mov         dword ptr [val],ecx  

    return val > 0;
010C4871  cmp         dword ptr [val],0  
010C4875  jle         SomeClass::IsPositiveClassMember+20h (010C4880h)  
010C4877  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],1  
010C487E  jmp         SomeClass::IsPositiveClassMember+27h (010C4887h)  
010C4880  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
010C4887  mov         al,byte ptr [ebp-4]
```

vs.

```
    int val = GetMember();
010C4829  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
010C482C  call        SomeClass::GetMember (010C1168h)  
010C4831  mov         dword ptr [val],eax  

    return val > 0;
010C4834  cmp         dword ptr [val],0  
010C4838  jle         SomeClass::IsPositiveGetMember+23h (010C4843h)  
010C483A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],1  
010C4841  jmp         SomeClass::IsPositiveGetMember+2Ah (010C484Ah)  
010C4843  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
010C484A  mov         al,byte ptr [ebp-4]
```

The second example calls `SomeClass::GetMember`, which has its own disassembly. So in the second case, instead of just loading the value from member, it makes a function call.

```
    return classMember;
010C4817  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
010C481A  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax]
```

You'll note that the instructions to load val with the value of classMember are identical, so the overhead comes from the `Call SomeClass::GetMember`.

This is in `debug` mode however, with no optimization. If we optimize, and build in release, we see the following disassembly:

```
    int val = classMember;

    return val > 0;
013D4830  xor         eax,eax  
013D4832  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],eax  
013D4834  setg        al
```

vs

```
    int val = GetMember();

    return val > 0;
013D4820  xor         eax,eax  
013D4822  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],eax  
013D4824  setg        al
```

The compiler optimizes away the call, and there is no difference.

Comment: This answer is an hour old and no upvotes other than mine? Heresy.

Answer (score 0):

Its purely depend on the need of programmer.

When to create function?

1. To increase the modularity of the program
2. When some common tasks are performed repeatedly.

In your case say suppose two number to be added.

For that you may use

```
int a= data member 1 + data member 2
```

Say suppose you have to use that at many places.

Then you have consider the point number 2.

You can just create the function like `addnumber()` this for ease of use and readability.

Regarding performance,

Both are same because the `member function are inline by default` when defined inside class definition. So separate stack allocation for calling that function is not required

Answer (score 0):

Using GetMember() might be a bit slower, unless its made inline explicitly or implicitly by your compiler.

However, using an accessor can greatly help your debugging, temporarily changing this:

```
int SomeClass::GetMember()
{
   return classMember;
}
```

into this:

```
int SomeClass::GetMember()
{
   std::cout << "GetMember() called when classMember=" << classMember << std::endl;
   return classMember;
}
```

But this might be a bit oldschool.